# How to archive with ignoring files larger than 100MB

Tags: tar, archive, compression, file-size

I'm trying to archive files with tar and ignoring files larger than 100MB. Is that possible? 
PS: Not have to use tar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah there are probably a few more ways of doing this but you're probably best off with `find` as it's so tunable.

```
find /path/to/dir -size -100M | xargs tar cvf archive.tar
```

or

```
tar cvf archive.tar $(find /path/to/dir -size -100M)
```

If there are other directories in the current folder which you do not want to archive, then use:

```
find /path/to/dir -maxdepth 1 -size -100M | xargs tar cvf archive.tar
```

---

Per the comments below, spaces can throw out some errors but in my testing they still seemed to get added to the archive when using the first method (a little strange in itself) but if you're worried, you can fix the find command to replace spaces with escaped versions.

As ever, there are a billion ways of doing this.

```
find /path/ -size -100M | sed 's/ /\\ /g' | xargs tar cvf archive.tar

find /path/ -size -100M -exec echo '"{}"' \; | xargs tar cvf archive.tar
```

Comment: Both options could give problems if the OP has filenames containing spaces.

Comment: ... agreed - will need to use `-print0` in the find command as well as `--null` for the tar command to cope with this scenario.

Comment: While creating a huge archive `tar cvf myfile.tar` command fails. I strongly suggest use to `tar rvf myfile.tar` command.

Comment: In case someone uses this to filter out files of smaller size, it might be useful to read this first: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275925/why-does-find-size-1g-not-find-any-files . TL;DR `-size -1k` doesn't work as expected, and might select only files that have a size of 0. You might need to use `! -size +1k`. (Same for `1M`, `1G`, etc.)

Comment: And in case you use `xargs`, make sure to add `-d '\n'` or `xargs` will break if `find` finds files with whitespaces in their names. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758525/make-xargs-handle-filenames-that-contain-spaces

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude the big files like this:

tar cf archive.tar /path/to/archive --exclude-from <(find  /path/to/archive -size +100M)